# Can I put the burner head in the oven during self cleaning?

Tags: cleaning, maintenance, oven, stove, stove-top

My renter moved out an left [a grimy mess](https://plus.google.com/photos/114445363669080969088/albums/5978660890561475121/5979041205371978834?authkey=CLDF6LqSkcXUWg&pid=5979041205371978834&oid=114445363669080969088).  The filth on the stove top actually backed-up into the nooks and carnies of surface burner head, and seems almost impassible to clean.

### Since the surface burner heads (figure 1) do not have an enamel coating, I was wondering, is it safe to stick them in the oven during the self clean cycle?

### If so, would I be able to put the enameled surface burner caps (figure 2) and grates in as well?

**Figure 1:** Burner head designs make them hard to clean:
[image: Hard to clean burner head]

**Figure 2:** Burner caps have a flat enameled surface and are generally easier to clean:
[image]

<sub>Images sourced from amazon</sub>

Comment: Ugh! Some people. Too bad you can't put the whole range in for self clean!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The self-clean temperature won't get high enough to melt the metal -- and the burner pieces are subject to pretty high heat anyway.  I have cleaned aluminum and enameled parts in a self-clean cycle and the only time I have had problems is with large surface-area part (think a frying pan or something) -- in this case you might warp the metal by subjecting it to such high heat.  I think the pieces you have will be just fine.

Comment: Tried it last night, both the burner head and the burner cap came out clean and undamaged!!!!  I'm trying it with the burner grates now!  :-)

Comment: I put all three - burner heads, caps and grates - in a self cleaning cycle once a year with no problem.

Answer (score 0):

That's not paint, it's an enamel. I think that any of the flame-contact steel parts should be just fine (sometimes there are aluminum parts, which I'd feel less comfortable with).  Magnets stick to steel not to aluminum, that's how you can tell.

Comment: The "burner head" is an aluminium alloy; the "burner cap" is steel with an enamel. The cap is a smooth surface and thus easier to clean than the head; hence my main concern is about the burner head.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience I actually forgot about my non stick frying pan in when I turn the self clean on and there was absolutely nothing left except a small pile of ash.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/138295)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).